# trying to understand the Singleton concept in objective-c with many variables

Tags: objective-c, oop, design-patterns, singleton

I'm trying to understand the Singleton concept in objective-c.

Most examples that I did found just refer to a single variable.

I'm a bit lost about how to adapt the examples to handle many variables as per an example the accelerometer values that return x, y, z.

Can you guide me a bit further ?

Comment: instead of one variable use 3....

Answer (score 4):

A **Singleton** refers to a special object that can only exist once inside the lifespan of your application. That object can have as many variables and properties as necessary.

```
//  Singleton.h

@interface Singleton : NSObject

@property (readwrite) int propertyA;
@property (readwrite) int propertyB;
@property (readwrite) int propertyC;

+ (Singleton *)sharedInstance;

@end
```

The key to a **Singleton** is that it can only be created once. Usually in Objective-C we use the `@synchronized()` directive to make sure it only gets created once. We put this in a convenience class method called `sharedInstance` and return our **Singleton**. Since the Singleton is just an object it can easily have multiple properties, variables, and methods.

//  Singleton.m

```
#import "Singleton.h"

@interface Singleton ()
{
    int variableA;
    int variableB;
    int variableC;
}
@end

@implementation Singleton

static Singleton *sharedInstance = nil;

+ (Singleton *)sharedInstance
{
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (sharedInstance == nil) {
            sharedInstance = [[Singleton alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (sharedInstance == nil) {
            sharedInstance = [super allocWithZone:zone];
            return sharedInstance;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Inits
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

This is not the ONLY way to create a **Singleton**. Remember the important part is it can only be created once. So you can take advantage of newer Grand Central Dispatch calls when developing for OSX and iOS such as `dispatch_once`.

**Talking to the Singleton**

So lets say you have another object elsewhere talking to the **Singleton**. This can be done anywhere you `#import "Singleton.h"`

```
- (void)someMethod
{
    // Setting properties
    int valueA = 5;
    [[Singleton sharedInstance] setPropertyA:valueA];

    // Reading properties
    int valueB = [[Singleton sharedInstance] propertyB];
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks.The last thing I do not understand is how to assign a value to a, b, or c and also how to get a value from a, b, or c. Thanks Regis

Comment: I've added a bit to show you how to access properties. variables are internal only and can't be assigned outside the singleton.

Comment: I suggest checking out this tutorial on basic Objective-C programming :) it will help. http://www.raywenderlich.com/21320/objectively-speaking-a-crash-course-in-objective-c-ios6